Is the set of Finite rank Operator closed compared to compact operators set

Let K(X,Y) be the set of compact operators from X to Y. Let F(X,Y) be the set of finite rank operators from X to Y. Is F closed sub space of K?

I proved every finite rank operator is compact. But I'm not sure if F is closed with respect to K.
I thought of the example: $X=Y=\ell _2$ and $A_n (x) = (x_1 ,x_2 ,...,x_n ,0 ,0....)$
So $rank A_n =n$ and $lim A_n = I$ where $I$ is identity. But the identity is not compact, so this example does not hold.

If you are talking Hilbert spaces, $F(X,Y)$ is dense in $K(X,Y)$. The same is not necessarily true for arbitrary Banach spaces. But even for Banach spaces, $F(X,Y)$ is not closed if $\dim X=\dim Y=\infty$. Indeed, given an infinite linearly independent sequence $\{e_n\}\subset Y$ with $\|e_n\|\leq1$, choose linearly independent $\{f_n\}\subset X^*$ with $\|f_n\|=1$ for all $n$, and form $T:X\to Y$ given by
$$
Tx=\sum_n2^{-n}f_n(x)e_n. 
$$
Then $T=\lim_k\sum_{n=1}^k2^{_n}f_n(x)e_n$, and each finite sum is in $F(X,Y)$. In particular $T\in K(X,Y)$. And $T$ is not finite-rank.
